# Sanity check, using Math.Round to round up to two decimal places

Tags: c#

Out of curiosity why does the following test fail? Doesn't Math.Round, round up?

```
    [Test]
    public void MathRound()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(7.13, Math.Round(7.125,2));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)...

Comment: @JeffMercado: While I'd normally agree, I don't believe that's relevant in this particular case.

Comment: @Jon: Well, maybe not directly, but it does talk about rounding to evens (which is the problem here). Had he known about this behavior, he'd be less surprised that the `Math.Round()` call will not round up here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation (looking at `Round(double, int)`:

> Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to a specified number of fractional digits, and rounds midpoint values to the nearest even number (example).

Your value is exactly 7.125 (there's no lack of precision here) and it *is* in the midpoint in the value after the digit you're rounding to, so that digit is rounded to even.

If you want a midpoint rounding mode of "round up", you should say so:

```
Assert.AreEqual(7.13, Math.Round(7.125, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

(You should usually provide a tolerance to `Assert.AreEqual` when comparing `double` values anyway, but that's a separate discussion.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, that solved it. My bad on not digging deeper in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following Method which compares Objects:

AreEqual(Object, Object)...Verifies that two specified objects are equal. The assertion fails if the objects are not equal.

You can attempt to use the following method that compares doubles to see if you get different results:

AreEqual(Double, Double, Double)...Verifies that two specified doubles are equal, or within the specified accuracy of each other. The assertion fails if they are not within the specified accuracy of each other.